# How to get window application status in python

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm currently writing a piece of code to test windows app based on pyautowin.

When of the test is to check if we can minimized the window.

Below is the code:

```
MyApp.Start_(bittorrentApp)
time.sleep(2)
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Bittorrent Automation Task', class_name='WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.2bf8098_r15_ad1')[0]
window = MyApp.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.Click()
window.ClickInput(coords = (300,10))
time.sleep(1)
lStyles = win32api.GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE);
if( lStyles & WS_MINIMIZE ):
    print "minimized"
else:
    print "not minimized"
```

I have imported win32api and I can minimized the window.

By the way

```
lStyles = win32api.GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE);
```

return an error, saying GWL_STYLE is not defined

Any idea ?

Comment: I have imported now the win32con and change GWL_STYLE to win32con.GWL_STYLE it works better but the GetWindowLong complain about a missing parameter. I think the missing parameters should refer to the window. How could I get the window ID of the application

Answer (score 0):

pywinauto already has all such functionality.

```
if window.HasStyle(pywinauto.win32defines.WS_MINIMIZE):
    window.Minimize()
```

That's all in HwndWrapper class. You can see all its attributes when typing window.WrapperObject(). in popup hint. WrapperObject() call is usually hidden for readability, but it's called implicitly anyway.

BTW, GetWindowLong(handle, style) has 2 parameters.